# Twig - How to loop particular number of times

Tags: loops, for-loop, twig

I need to be able to generate the links certain number of times (stored in int variable)Is there a way to do it out of the box with twig's for loop?

```
{% for i in numberOfLoops %}
    {{ i }}. Some data
{% endfor %}
```

The above example do not work. I googled it but did not find actual solution. Any support would be very appreciated.

EDIT:
I also tried:

```
{% set k = 10 %}
{% for i in 0..k %}
    {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

but this generates an exception:

```
com.lyncode.jtwig.exception.ParseException: Wrong binary operation syntax
Explanation: Input position (line 15, pos 27):
        {% for i in 0..k %}
                      ^
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I found the working example:

```
{% set k = 10 %}
{% for i in range(1, k) %}
    {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

Source: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html (not very intuitive to find indeed).

Comment: Why not just `{% for i in range (1, 10) %}`

Comment: @AlexanderRechsteiner part of the question is to have the number of times "stored in int variable", k in this example.

Comment: @AlexanderRechsteiner part of the question is to have the number of times "stored in int variable", k in this example.

Comment: omg i had the hardest time finding this info ! twig seems so stuck up in the view that the user will only ever need to loop over an existing array that they really didn't plan anything regarding a basic for loop

Answer (score 17):

I already had a loop in place to iterate over, I solved this for myself with the slice filter.

```
{% for link in links|slice(0, 12) %}
```

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#iterating-over-a-subset

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
{% set k = 10 %}
{% for i in 0..k %}
    {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

Documentation: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this gives an error: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is com.lyncode.jtwig.exception.ParseException: Wrong binary operation syntax
Explanation: Input position (line 14, pos 27):
            {% for i in 0..k %}

Comment: This code run ins my twig templates. Maybe you have a different version running in you project.

Comment: I see. You may be right, but anyway for me it did not work. And what about the above solution (for you)?

Comment: That depends on your Twig version I guess. The code works perfectly fine with my templates.

Comment: This always loops at least once. I don't want it to loop if `k = 0` for example.